# why my label formatter is not working as expected in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to do dynamic texting for my x axis's label. Basically if the label with same month year has been displayed, I do not want to repeat them.
However, in my jsfiddle example, it somehow doesn't work (even though it does return the wanted text). What am I doing wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/daxu/md2zk/64/

```
                if (labelYear == -1 || year != labelYear) {
                    $('#MessagePerformanceChartContainerID').data("FirstYear", year);
                    if (labelYear == -1)
                    {
                        usedLabels = [];
                    }
                    usedLabels.push(curr_month + ' ' + curr_year);
                    $('#MessagePerformanceChartContainerID').data("UsedLabels", usedLabels);
                    ////first one so
                    return curr_month + ' ' + curr_year;
                }
                else{
                    var usedLabel = curr_month + ' ' + curr_year;
                    if ( $.inArray(usedLabel, usedLabels) != -1)
                    {
                        usedLabel = curr_day + ' ' + curr_month + ' ' + curr_year;
                        return 'a';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        usedLabels.push(usedLabel);
$('#MessagePerformanceChartContainerID').data("UsedLabels", usedLabels);

                        alert(usedLabel);
                        return usedLabel;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just formatter is called twice :) See JS console: http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/66/ - each timestamp is listed twice.

As solution, I would clean up `UsedLabels` in `tickPositioner`:

```
$('#MessagePerformanceChartContainerID').data("UsedLabels", []);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/md2zk/67/